# enumitem.sty not found

Tags: lyx, mactex

I'm trying to compile a document on Lyx but it keeps throwing 'enumitem.sty' not found.

I installed the BasicTeX package from MacTeX website.

Is there anything else I need to install?

Comment: I'm pretty amazed `enumitem` doesn't fall in the 'basic' category.  I'd guess BasicTeX has a package install mechanism, but, if not, you can always install it directly from [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem).  If you just want to test quickly if that works, put `enumitem.sty` in the same folder as your `.tex` file and try to compile.  If that works, you probably want to move the file to a more useful spot in your installation.  How that is done varies from OS to OS and from 'TeX distribution' to 'TeX distribution'.  There are many questions on this site about such matters.

Comment: Is there any solution to install all the packages at once? Will I have to install the whole MacTeX installation?

Comment: BasicTeX is extremely... well... basic. Unless you are seriously pushed for space, you are much better off installing the lot and forgetting about it. Otherwise, you will have to keep adding package after package as you find you need them. I don't understand your comment really. Yes, there is a solution which installs all the packages at once. It is called MacTeX. But you apparently want to install everything without installing MacTeX which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Does you code include \usepackage{enumitem}?  That would cause the error, since I don't believe there is such a package.

Comment: @JohnKormylo -- but there really is an `enumitem` package, included in tex live (full) and on ctan.

Comment: I ended up installing the full MacTex. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in the comments, BasicTeX contains what is strictly necessary for TeX and LaTeX to work, and very little more.

If you don't want to install the full MacTeX (which is the full TeX Live, adapted for Mac OS X) and if you want to stick to BasicTeX, you can install the enumitem package yourself. The simplest way to do it is to use the  [TeX Live Utility](https://code.google.com/p/mactlmgr/wiki/GettingStarted)  program, which comes with the MacTeX-additions (everything of MacTeX excepted TeX Live). BTW, it is strongly recommended to install these MacTeX-additions together with BasicTeX, if only to install the packages you think are missing…

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me.

```
sudo tlmgr install enumitem
```

In case if tlmgr is not found edit .bash_profile using `vim ~/.bash_profile`

and add these lines

```
### TeX
export PATH="/Library/TeX/Distributions/.DefaultTeX/Contents/Programs/texbin:$PATH"
```

Run `source ~/.bash_profile`

And then run the above command.

Comment: This worked for me

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Tex Live after you install using:

```
sudo tlmgr install enumitem
```

You will need to update the index using

```
sudo texhash
```

Before the package can be found.

See "4 Update your index" in https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Installing_Extra_Packages